# Longtable continues into footer

Tags: header-footer, longtable

I am using the longtable package to span tables across multiple pages. However sometimes (to me randomly, however so far only i quite complex documents) the longtable doesn't break like intended, but continues into the footer.

[image: Longtable penetrating the footer instead of breaking correctly (image)]

I tried to come up with a simple minimal example, but the tex files contained in Example1.7z file (link below) was the best i could do.

[Example tex files (deep link)](http://peecee.dk/upload/download/392262)

Answer (score 3):

Could you really not make a more minimal example? `longtable` is a bit confused by the floating table. If you put `\clearpage` in front of that table it gets back in sync.

I do not have all the packages you referenced but could still see the effect if I ignored the missing package error (so clearly the example could be more minimal)

You also want to remove all `\begin{center}` around your longtables as they have no affect on centering and just produce anomalous vertical space. Also

```
\newcommand{\mytable}[4]{
  \begin{table}[htp!]
```

not including `t` is an error (LaTeX warns of that when you run the file, and not including `p` makes it far more likely the table foes to the end of the document.

and you have a missing percent here

```
  \end{table}%
}
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct about your points. However they don't affect the actual problem. I considered the \clearpage solution as a last resort, as it look a bit weird to clear the page if the table is small.

I will try to make a more minimal example and update the question.

Comment: Needing the manual \clearpage isn't ideal but it is what is needed (if longtable had correctly detected the earlier table it would have added the clearpage itself). the table isn't that small in particular it does not fit in the space at the bottom of the page so a page break before the table is exactly what you need (although it would be better if it was automatically added)

Comment: The tex code is generated in C# on runtime from data extracted from a DB. Hence i can't put in the \clearpage manually when needed, as the table could contain anything from 1 to 200 rows. Maybe i should have pointed that out earlier, but i didn't think it was relevant to the problem at hand.

The example files have been updated, the example is a bit simpler now.

Answer (score 0):

Delete `\begin{table} \end{table}` and move `\caption{} \label{}` into `\begin{longtable}` then you'll solve your problem.

Above is the solution I found when I met the same problem.

I cannot open your code link, so it might not be your perfect answer.